# EE 2.6 Relationships, or Playa?

Tags: channel-entries, playa, relationships

I'm building quite a complex travel company site, where things like different vacation packages need to be linked to different modes of transport, hotels, various different statuses and categories etc.

For example, a tour might have 4 different trains and a boat. I have created a channel, Trains, and another channel, Boats. I'm wondering what the best way to link these up is.

**What are the advantages/disadvantages of using EE 2.6's improved Relationships feature vs something more comprehensive like Playa?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

My decision to use playa over Ellis' new relationships, is based on:

1) When you buy an addon from a top-notch developer like Brandon Kelly, it comes with developer support, which can include timely addition of future features that you request v. paying for a support plan from Ellis if you don't have one already.

2} Playa has been vetted for many years in the real world by a very large number of users with very complex needs

3) Playa is much more robust.  It is well integrated with the P & T first class add-on line-up and many other very popular add-ons.

4) It is low variables compatible

5) When the user community supports our top-notch developer community, we keep EE excellent.

Comment: especially 2) is an excellent reason - Playa is a very mature add-on with tag parameters and variables for a large number of scenarios. It'll be a while before EE's native relations will be able to catch up with this.

Comment: The relationship field should work fine. However, if you think you'll need to filter the related entries on the publish page by category, author, member group, or status, then save yourself the hassle and go with Playa. 

I do believe Playa will convert a relationship field to a Playa field and keep all the relationships. I'm not sure if this is still true with the new relationship field in 2.6.

Comment: @NunoAlbuquerque - Now you can; Playa offers conversion-scripts for Solspace Related Entries and Ellislab Relationship Fields: http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/using/converting/index.html